# Cryptography "cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken" while loop with functools.partial

Tags: python, cryptography, functools

I'm getting an `cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken` error only when I want decrypt data while using `functools.partial` for iterate into a file.

```
key = Fernet.generate_key()
print(key)
cypher = Fernet(key)


def encryypt():
    with open('file.pdf', 'rb') as f, open('file2.pdf', 'wb') as target_f: 
        for _bytes in iter(partial(f.read, 10*2048), ''):
            encrypt_data = cypher.encrypt(_bytes)
            target_f.write(encrypt_data)
            if not _bytes:break
    target_f.close()

def decryypt() :
    with open('file2.pdf', 'rb') as ff, open('file3.pdf', 'wb') as target_ff: 
        for __bytes in iter(partial(ff.read, 10*2048), ''):
            decrypt_data = cypher.decrypt(__bytes)
            target_ff.write(decrypt_data)
            if not __bytes:break
encryypt()
decryypt()
```

The encrypt() function works perfectly, but fails for decrypt() with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\#\#\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 134, in _verify_signature
    h.verify(data[-32:])
cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\#\#\Bin2\Start\test.py", line 43, in <module>
    decryypt()
  File "c:\Users\#\#\Bin2\Start\test.py", line 39, in decryypt
    decrypt_data = cypher.decrypt(__bytes)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\#\#\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 91, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, time_info)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\#\#\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 152, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "C:\Users\#\#\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 136, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Same key and same cypher are used, I'm sure it's a problem with the iteration.

Comment: Fernet doesn't really support *streaming* encryption and decryption. It's designed to encrypt and decrypt a single *message* per instance. I suppose it's possible to make it work by interpreting sequential chunks of the plaintext file as *messages*, but the resulting cipher chunk is *longer* than the plaintext so this must somehow be accounted for during decryption, but you haven't done this.

Comment: Yes i understand, why that do not work now... Thank you for your answer.
This post helped me for my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312922/how-to-encrypt-large-file-using-python

Answer (score 0):

So like President James K.Polk said, Fernet it's not meant for encrypt big date or streaming data.

**From the doc** :

> Limitations :
>
> Fernet is ideal for encrypting data that easily fits in memory. As a
> design feature it does not expose unauthenticated bytes. This means
> that the complete message contents must be available in memory, making
> Fernet generally unsuitable for very large files at this time.

So the only way to encrypt data through iteration with ***Fernet*** is to chunk data then encrypt it.

In the following code, we will chunk the file into blocks of 6MB, then encrypt it.

```
in_file = 'linux.zip'
enc_file = 'linux_enc.zip'
out_file = 'linux_out.zip'
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cypher = Fernet(key)


def encryypt():
    with open(in_file, 'rb') as f, open(enc_file, 'wb') as target_f: 
        for _bytes in iter(partial(f.read,600000), ''):
            if not _bytes:break
            encrypted_data = cypher.encrypt(_bytes)
            target_f.write(encrypted_data)
            print(f'encrypted block size:{str(len(encrypted_data))}')  
    target_f.close()

def decryypt() :
    with open(enc_file, 'rb') as ff, open(out_file, 'wb') as target_ff: 
        for __bytes in iter(partial(ff.read,800100), ''):
            if not __bytes:break
            decrypted_data = cypher.decrypt(__bytes)
            target_ff.write(decrypted_data)
            print(f'decrypted block size:{str(len(decrypted_data))}')  
        target_ff.close()
encryypt()
decryypt()
```

And for decryption we need to increase the chunk size because the file is bigger after the encryption.

For encrypt a chunk of 6000000 bytes, we have to decrypt a chunk of 8000100 bytes.